# Mutli-User Firebase Database

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, authentication, multi-user

I'm trying to create a sign up screen in Xcode that allows a user to pick a "account type" designer, singer etc. that then groups those individuals together and creates their account, grouping them by their account type.

I am able to create accounts and store them within my Firebase database  and I have the drop box with all the account types but I don't understand or know how to create these account types and attach them as identifiers of each user upon sign up.

Comment: please add some code snippets. what you tried and what problems you are facing. without code its hard to help

Comment: Generally, there would be a /users node in which 'other' information could be stored about the user. /user/uid/favorite_food or /user/uid/location or for your use case /users/uid/account_type. You don't need to 'group them' in any way other than that as you can load their account type from their users/uid node when they log in.